# Elegant way of cleaning up multiple resources when exceptions may be thrown

Tags: c#, exception, resources

I'm working in some code that uses exceptions a lot to handle certain error conditions (certainly not the best design by any means, but it's what I'm working with).

When an exception occurs in code, I need an elegant way of cleaning up any open or temporary resources.

This can be performed like this:

```
try
{
    foo();
    bar();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Oops, an error occurred - let's clean up resources
    // Any attempt to cleanup non-existent resources will throw
    // an exception, so let's wrap this in another try block
    try
    {
        cleanupResourceFoo();
        cleanupResourceBar();
    }
    catch
    {
        // A resource didn't exist - this is non-fatal so let's drop
        // this exception
    }
}
```

Let's say that the `foo()` method cleaned up after itself properly, but the `bar()` method threw an exception.  In the cleanup code, we will call `cleanupResourceFoo()` **first** which itself will throw an exception as the `foo` resources have already been cleaned up.

This means that `cleanupResourceBar()` won't end up being called and we'll end up with a resource leak.

Of course we could re-write the inner `try/catch` block like so:

```
try
{
    cleanupResourceFoo();
}
catch
{
}
try
{
    cleanupResourceBar();
}
catch
{
}
```

but now we're getting pretty ugly.

I come from a C++ background and this is the kind of thing I would normally use RAII for.  Any recommendations about an elegant way to handle this in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cleaning up resources should almost always be handled via `using` statements and `IDisposable` - so you'd simply have:

```
using (FirstResource r1 = ...)
{
    using (SecondResource r2 = ...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you *only* want to clean up resources on exception, that's somewhat rarer - and not something I'd expect RAII to particularly help you with in C++. You could potentially use delegates to make this simpler:

```
TryWithCleanUpOnException(foo, cleanUpResourceFoo);
TryWithCleanUpOnException(bar, cleanUpResourceBar);

...

private static void TryWithCleanUpOnException(Action action,
                                              Action cleanUp)
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        action();
        success = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!success)
        {
            cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

By not *catching* the exception, this allows errors to propagate rather than being swallowed. This is *normally* what you want - if it isn't in your case, perhaps you could explain more precisely what your situation is.

You've said that there are non-fatal exceptions that you effectively want to ignore - but you generally shouldn't just catch `Exception` and keep going: catch *specific* exceptions that you expect in particular situations. Obviously you may have a very special situation, but this is general advice which holds most of the time. You can restructure the helper method above to catch exception if you really want.

Comment: Okay, so I understand how `using` limits the scope of the resource, but not sure what you mean by `IDisposable`.  My (limited) understanding of C# is that most (?) objects inherit from `IDisposable`.  Is that correct?  How does it help in my situation?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx for an elaborate example.

Comment: When a program reaches the end of the scope, a runtime calls `Dispose()` method which is declared in `IDisposable`. If you want to use `using` with your resources you need to inherit this interface and implement a way of cleaning the resources up

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: Only types which require disposal implement IDisposable - it's specifically designed to indicate that the type *does* require disposal, and the `using` statement supports it directly.

Comment: What happens if the resource in question is a database entry?  e.g. foo() will add a table row at the start of the method, and delete it if it reaches the end, but if it doesn't reach the end, we need to delete it in the exception handler?  Is this where your delegate approach would work best?

Comment: That last point about catching specific exceptions is a great one, and one the code isn't adhering to at present.  Thanks Jon for your great answer (as always).

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: I failed to reply to your previous comment: I'd use a transaction which implemented IDisposable, and which would be rolled back if it hadn't been explicitly committed.

Comment: Can you point me to any sample code that does that?  Thanks again.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: The strandard ADO.NET transaction classes behave that way, I believe - so you'd just have a `using` statement for the transaction, and at the end of the block you'd commit the transaction.